# Communicate floating button with multiple Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to communicate one floating Button that will be used by many Fragments.
Every time user clicks the Button it will execute any chosen Fragment.

How is it possible to use one floating Button for some Fragments?

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: define button in activity, probably make a callback interface, when button is clicked, invoke callback listener.
If there are multiple fragments listening at once, try using observer pattern.

Comment: Thanks @azizbekian

Comment: If I can give the details. I want a FAB (Floating Action Button) which is in the Main-Activity can be used for 3 fragments. Each fragment will only have 2 EditTexts (Users input data), whenever the users click the FAB it will execute the fragment activity the users placed their data. So How is it possible to make it works well? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I call a view (FAB - Floating Action Button) in [Main activiyt]  by using View fabKocok = getView().findViewById(R.id.fabkocok);  then i made an interface method  public interface OnTabKocokListener(){
    }
        public void kocokHaislData(String textViewCard); then i had implemented it on my Main activity: public class KocokMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabKocok.OnTabKocokListener{           . but when i tried to call it by using alt + insert (Implement abstract method) i could not find the method, can somebody help me please.

Comment: and also i get this error: D:\Android Program By Nando\APP\Kocok-Kocok2\app\src\main\java\com\theinmark\fernando\kocok_kocok2\TabKocok.java
Error:(109, 40) error: '{' expected
Error:(113, 2) error: reached end of file while parsing
Error:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.